# clear contents vba

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I TRY THIS CODE BUT IT DOESNT WORK

```
Range("L3:ED3").Formula = "=IF(C3=0,L3:ED3,"",IF(C3>0,L3:ED3)).clearcontents"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It seems like you are mixing VBA and Excel Formulas up. You  should logically explain what you are trying to do rather than show us a code that doesn't work.

Comment: yes  sir,thanks for the reply.i want to  clear contents on l3:ed3 if the the cell c3 is empty.there is vba code for this..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA code to clear the range ("I3:ED3") if cell ("C3") is empty, then you will want to create a Worksheet_Change code. Open Visual Basic Editor (Alt + F11), On the left side under VBAProject in the Project Explorer, Click on Microsoft Excel Objects, and ***Double Click*** the sheet that you want this code to work on (If you don't see the window to the left, click ***Ctrl + r*** to open the Project Explorer) . In my example I selected "Sheet1" to paste this code in. Once you are in the Worksheet module for the corresponding sheet, paste the code below.
[image]

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("C3").Value = "" Then Range("I3:ED3").ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```